# Whether a set is closed or not

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Denote by $C_{[0,1]}$ the ternary Cantor set on $[0,1]$. Now consider $[0,1] \setminus C_{[0,1]}$. It contains open intervals. Now define Cantor sets on all these open intervals by simply translating and dilating the standard Cantor set. Denote them as $C_{[a_i,b_i]}$. Now is the set $F=C_{[0,1]} \cup \bigcup C_{[a_i,b_i]}$ closed?

My try: I wanted to show that its complement is open. I argued that the complement of $F$ consists of open intervals. So $F^c$ consists of unions of open intervals. Hence $F$ is closed. But my professor says it is not so. Is it because the open intervals are getting smaller every time? I do not understand where i am going wrong. Can any one please tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Give me an open set in the complement of this set ? :D

Comment: Here the problem is : It is the infinite union of closed sets, which may not be closed. Also the you don't have the original complement of $C_{[0,1]}$ anymore as you have played Cantor game on it. :)

Comment: @DiffeoR the open interval (4/9,5/9) is in the complement since it is not included in $C_{[1/3,2/3]}$

Comment: @DiffeoR but i am able to get open intervals and unions of open intervals is open

Comment: @user129901 But you're not _unioning_ the open intervals, you're _intersecting_ unions of them (if you see this as constructing the complement of $F$).

Comment: @Arthur but i am not filling complement of all cantor set i am only filling it once that is i am only doing it once for C[0,1] for example the interval (4/9,5/9) is in the complement

Comment: @user129901 Ahh, I misunderstood the problem. Still, I don't think it's closed. I'll look into it.

Comment: I think your reasoning is right. The complement of the original cantor set is a union of open intervals. By replacing the gaps you just take the open intervals and replace them by more open intervals. And it can be done simultaneously. It doesn't matter how many open intervals you have or how big they are, their union is always open, so the complement should be closed.

Comment: @user2345215 some of the intervals where i am placing cantor set are quite small so is my argument still valid so if you can provide proof taking some general x it would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reworked solution after clearing up a misunderstanding of the question**

Take a point $x \notin F$. Then especially, it is not in $C_{[0, 1]}$, so it must be contained in some open interval $(a, b)$ in the complement of $C_{[0, 1]}$ (assume for simplicity that $(a, b)$ is maximal, so that $a, b \in C_{[0, 1]}$).

It is clear that $F\cap [a, b] = C_{[a, b]}$ is a (translated and uniformly shrinked) Cantor set. Since $x \notin F$ and therefore not in $C_{[a, b]}$, we have an interval $(c, d)\subseteq (a, b)$ containing $x$ that does not intersect $F\cap[a, b]$. Hence $(c, d)$ does not intersect $F$, and since $x$ was arbitrary, this shows that $F$ is closed.

Comment: I didn't even rate, but isn't he talking about just one step in the process? Adding smaller cantor sets to all gaps in the original? That should be closed.